# Differential Expresion Comparisons

Tags: group-differences, genetics

In a Differential expression experiment concerning a gene of interest there is an upregulated condition, downregulated condition and control. When comparing these, it obviously makes sense to compare both conditions against the control. However, when comparing the upregulated condition against the downregulated condition, what are we getting out of this and how can we interpret this?

What I am trying to get at is how powerful are comparisons of the two experimental conditions against each other as opposed to the same two experimental conditions compared to the control?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you highlight the *statistical* nature of your question? I wonder if this would be a better fit on the [biology.SE] SE site.

Comment: *Edited to better reflect the statistical nature

Answer (score 0):

You should include the treatment as a factor with 3 levels: "Control", "Up" and "down", using dummy variables in a regression model with the expression level as dependent variable. The coefficients will be interpretable in terms of differences between the different conditions.